# Passing through lists from jQuery to the service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm sure I've done this in another solution, but I can't seem to find any solution as to do it again and wondered if anyone can help me...

This is my WebAPI code:

```
public class WebController : ApiController
{
        public void Get(string telephone, string postcode, List<Client> clients)
        {

        }
}
```

And, calling this from jQuery:

```
    function Client(name, age) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
    }

    var Clients = [];
    Clients.push(new Client("Chris", 27));

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Web/",
        data: { telephone: "999", postcode: "xxx xxx", clients: Clients }
    });
```

But the "clients" object always comes back as null. I've also tried `JSON.stringify(Clients)`, and this is the same result. Can anyone see anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: did u debug with firebug? or browser?

Comment: Yep, the values are going through fine in Firebug. As both parameters arrays and, when JSON.stringify is called, an array string. I.e.  clients [{"Name":"Chris","Age":27}]

Comment: so you get back a response? but having problem with jquery?

Comment: The parameters are going to the service, the telephone and postcode parameters, but the "clients" parameter isn't being picked up on the server side. There must be something wrong with the translation between jQuery and the WebAPI, but just can't seem to find what.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action parameter binding in Web API is different than in ASP.NET MVC (you can read more about it [in this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)):

- "simple" types (string, int, etc) are bound from the URI
- "complex" types are bound from the request body

If you don't want to follow the conventions you need to mark your parameters with the `[FromBody]` or `[FromUri]` attribute depending from where do you want to bind them.

In you case because you are using a GET request you need to mark your `clients` param with `[FromUri]` to bind correctly:

```
public class WebController : ApiController
{
    public void Get(string telephone, 
                    string postcode, 
                    [FromUri]List<Client> clients)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much! I couldn't find find that link anywhere when I was searching for a solution, you're an absolute life saver!